# How to initialize a custom component programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, custom-component

I already know how to use a custom component in a xml. Now, I'm trying to call one programmatically. I haven't found any tutorial about this so I tried to do it like how we declare a view programmatically. One problem I stumbled upon is that how do I get an `AttributeSet` that I pass on my constructor? I don't know how I get or create that to pass it for my custom component.

This is my custom component class.

```
public class CheckOutItem extends ConstraintLayout {
    public Context ctx;
    public Paint mPaint;
    public Rect mRect;
    int mSquareColor;
    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView lblAbbrev, lblFullName;
    public ConstraintLayout lytMain;
    String TAG = "sharePOS";

    public CheckOutItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;
        init(null);
    }

    public CheckOutItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.checkout_item, this);
        ctx = context;

        init(attrs);
    }

    public CheckOutItem(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        ctx = context;
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(@Nullable AttributeSet set){
        //inflate(ctx, R.layout.checkout_item, this);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mRect = new Rect();

        if(set == null){
            return;
        }

        TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(set, R.styleable.CheckOutItem);

        this.imgThumbnail = findViewById(R.id.imgItemThumbnail);
        this.lblAbbrev = findViewById(R.id.lblItemAbbrevName);
        this.lblFullName = findViewById(R.id.lblItemFullName);
        this.lytMain = findViewById(R.id.lytMain);

        this.lblAbbrev.setText(ta.getText(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_abbrevText));
        this.lblAbbrev.setTextSize(ta.getDimension(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_abbrevTextSize, 1f));
        this.lblAbbrev.setTextColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_abbrevTextColor, Color.BLACK));

        this.lblFullName.setText(ta.getText(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameText));
        this.lblFullName.setTextSize(ta.getDimension(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameTextSize, 1f));
        this.lblFullName.setTextColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameTextColor, Color.BLACK));
        this.lblFullName.setBackgroundColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_fullNameBackgroundColor, Color.WHITE));

        this.lytMain.setBackgroundColor(ta.getColor(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_mainBackgroundColor, Color.LTGRAY));
        this.lytMain.setBackground(ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.CheckOutItem_mainBackgroundDrawable));

        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mRect.left = 0;
        mRect.right = getWidth();
        mRect.top = 0;
        mRect.bottom = getHeight();

        Log.d(TAG, "rect: " + mRect);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

How do I set a margin in the custom component? Regular `LayoutParams` with `setMargins()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have some reading to do. What you call a custom component is essentially your custom View. Your class CheckOutItem extends a ConstraintLayout, which in turn extends the class View. Already you should be able to use your custom View in XML, just go to any layout XML in your project and start typing "CheckOutItem". It should pop up as a code hint.

Comment: Yes I know that. What I want to know is how to get or create the `AttributeSet` needed by the custom component's constructor because I haven't found any tutorial about it.

Comment: As you can see, I already have that in my code.

Comment: you cannot create `AttributeSet` - you have to use `CheckOutItem(Context context)` and use some `set*` methods afterwards

Comment: Like CheckOutItem coi = new CheckOutItem(context); coi.setTextSize(14);?